# SSRS problem getting ASP.NET session has expired

Tags: .net, asp.net, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

when viewing the report in report viewer we get the following error ASP.NET session has expired

we use .NET 2005 ssrs 2005

well we have a report developed and hosted on SSRS server which is same as application server for ASPX applications

in our web application the default.aspx have a report viewer that shows the report

deployed on test server where the link to the application is http://testserver/appname
and report server link is http://testserver/reportserver

every thing is working fine

in production server

we have different sitename for the application which is http://applicationname
in production each application is defferent site

so here we have http://applicationname  for the webapplication
and http://servername/reportserver for the report

here the report viewer is not showing the report but giving the following error

ASP.NET session has expired

AspNetSessionExpiredException: ASP.NET session has expired]
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataOperation..ctor() +866
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.GetHandler() +719
   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +15
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +638
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +177

can i get some help please

**update :**
tested it on the production as http://productionserver/applicationname 
it is working fine (thats when i put the application as a virtual directory under the default site)
but when i put the application as saperate site http://applicationname on the same server i get the error ?!!!

Comment: strange behavior , found that this problem don't happen if i run the page from chrome but it is there if i run the page with any IE browsers , unfortunatly we have to support IE in our organization

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: tested on IE 8 and IE 6 since these two are still in use in our org

Comment: Looks like issue with cookies - IE is not sending the session cookie in one of the request. Will advise to use tool such as Fiddler to inspect requests/responses from IE - see if failed request contains ASP.NET session cookie. Check which resource the request is made to and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue. The report viewer would randomly pick when to show the report and the other times I would just get this error: "ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found".

After trying every possible solution on the web, I finally found that the issue was in the Process Model under the Advance Settings in the Application Pool.

The **Maximum Worker Process** was set to **2** and after changing the number to **1**, I was no longer getting an error "ASP.NET session has expired or could not be found".

Hopefully, I can help another person saving some time.

Here is a screenshot of what you need to change in the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Three things you can try from, the first two are from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1238835.aspx).

1) Change the default InProc Session-State mode to StateServer mode as following:

`<sessionState mode="StateServer" 
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=localhost:42424" 
              cookieless="false" 
              timeout="20"/>`

or

2) You may have an image in the Report. When you're taking the report to production, you might be forgeting to take the image that was embeded in the report as well.

or

3) Your IIS may be trying to spin up more processes or whatever - at any rate, set your maxworkingprocesses to 1 so it doesn't try to spin up new ones.

Comment: Dear Richard could explain solution 1. more please where to put this ?

Comment: See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx.

Comment: I think the main problem for me is the application is on defferent site than the reportserver but both on the same server , it is cookie problem most probably

Answer (score 1):

You may also encounter this issue if the path to the report includes an underscore.  I haven't identified a fix other than to remove them, but that does work (for us at least).

EG: `http://reportserverhost/Reports_Dev/SomeReport` had to become `http://reportserverhost/Reports Dev/SomeReport` in order to work.

Makes no sense to me but that's our fix.